# Facebook graph API returning null values

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook login works perfectly in my localhost, but when I uploaded it to a web server, **it can't fetch any data from the users.**
*I can only get their facebook id*, but the other infos are null or blank.

I think the facebook login works, because they got redirected to the `$redirect_url` that I initialized.

```
$app_id = "******";
$app_secret = "*******";
$redirect_url = "localhost/sample/";

try
{
    $facebook = FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
    $sess = $helper -> getSessionFromRedirect();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{

}


if(!isset($sess))
{    
    //facebook login button

    echo '<div class="fb"><a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl().'"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Sign in with Facebook</a></div>';

}
else
{
    $request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me');
    $response = $request->execute();                                                
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());                 
    $fb_id = $graph ->getId(); //this is the only data that i can get
    $fname = $graph ->getFirstName();
    $lname = $graph ->getLastName();
    $gender = $graph ->getGender();

    echo 'name: '.$fname.' '.$lname.' gender: '.$gender; // these are null or ''      

    $_SESSION['fb_session'] = $sess;
}
```

**I already got my permission approved.**

This is an fb account that i created. 
[image]

As it shown above, I think I'm not breaking any rules since I'm only fetching the info from the agreed permission.

Comment: You need to include which fields you want in the request. Changed in API v2.4

Comment: Looks like @WizKid 's comment is the right answer. I'd suggest to complete it with the modified line of code and post it as an answer

Answer (score -1):

It looks like FB requires that you include the Graph version in your request. Also, why not add some checks in the exceptions to see if it's a Graph issue or FB SDK. Also, is the user authenticating and you're just not getting their data, or are they not authenticating either?

Here is a snip that I've used and is on the FB Graph auth docs:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => '{app-id}',
 'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 // When validation fails or other local issues
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
}
```

This will also let it grab it's redirect_url for you from the app that you have registered with them.